# react-native-google-signin/google-signin: Correct way to write the flow for Google API calls?

Tags: react-native, google-api, google-signin

I have a React Native app (users will be iOS and Android), where the user can sign in to Google and then perform operations on their Google Calendar. I am using the Google REST API for Calendars, and the axios library for http calls. I am migrating to the /react-native-google-signin/google-signin package (I'm also using Expo, migrating away from AuthSession which dropped support for Google).

At some point the user may click the Google Sign-In button and the app will load their calendars and events, and then at some later point in time (possibly even after their Google accessToken expires) they may perform an operation on a calendar event. My question is, what is the correct and performant way to use the google-signin methods to manage the user's signed in status and accessToken?

For example, let's say the user wants to save a calendar event, which means the code will execute a PUT call for `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/[[calendarId]]/events/[[eventId]]`. I need to attach an accessToken to this call and I am currently using Axios interceptors:

```
googleApiClient.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {

  let tokens = await GoogleSignin.getTokens();
  let accessToken = tokens?.accessToken ?? '';

  config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
  console.log(`Google API call ${config?.method?.toUpperCase()} ${config.url}`, config.params);
  return config;
});
```

If the user has signed in previously but some time has passed and the session is now expired, the call to getTokens() throws an error "Error: getTokens requires a user to be signed in". I would like for this interceptor to be fast, and to recover a session if there is one as transparently as possible.

I am thinking I need to use some combination of .isSignedIn(), .signInSilently(), .getCurrentUser(), .getTokens() (and it seems like maybe I need to check for a 401 and then do .clearCachedAccessToken() + .getTokens() for Android?), but I'm confused on which combination is actually needed. I don't want to call all of them if I don't have to, and I'm also not clear on which ones may trigger network calls underneath the covers.

Can anyone please help shed some light on a recommended way to use all these methods together for my scenario?

I have tried my interceptor code to first check .isSignedIn(), however the docs state the current user might sill be null if the session is expired. So then I check the .getCurrentUser() to make sure it's not null. If it is null, then I run .signInSilently() to refresh the user. Only then, if I have a user at that point, can I run .getTokens() to acquire the accessToken. This seems like a lot of things to check, and if that's what I need to do then fine - but if there's a more streamlined way to ensure I have a valid accessToken then I'd like to do that instead.